# Cassandra Connection Pool for Flask

Tags: python, flask, cassandra

I am working on a REST web service built with Flask which needs to query a Cassandra database.  The most expensive part of the logic is creating the connection to the Cassandra cluster.

What do I need to do with Flask so that I do not have to create the connection to the Cluster on every request?

Comment: Try this: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/pool.html Flask doesn't change too much in the equation :)

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a tutorial or example showing how to properly use this feature?  I have been looking around and have not been able to find anything other than the page you linked to.

Comment: If you share the `session = cluster.connect()` object you should be good. It will automatically pool for you.

Comment: @Wolph I have tried this, it works for a short period of time, but then the Cassandra Driver will lose it's connection to the cluster and throw an error at every request.  The cluster is still up and if I restart uWSGI the web service will start functioning properly again.

Comment: I can't say I've ever manually written a client for Cassandra, but looking at the `cqlengine` source they appear to have a reconnect method to solve this: https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/master/cqlengine/connection.py#L70
Not the prettiest solution but it does the trick

Comment: @egerhard If you store the session object correctly it shouldn't loose its connection. Do you have your code on github so i can have a look at what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create new connection on every request, rather you should create a connection object for each process.

If you are running your flask application with uwsgi , I suggest to use @postfork decorator.
Say - You are spawning 4 processes with uwsgi, then
one session for each process is created after the process is spawned.

```
from uwsgidecorators import postfork
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import dict_factory
from cassandra.policies import RoundRobinPolicy

session = None
hosts=["127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2"]
keyspace="mykeyspace"

def get_new_session():
    global cluster
    cluster = Cluster(hosts, protocol_version=4, auth_provider=auth_provider, control_connection_timeout=None,
                  max_schema_agreement_wait=10, port=9042, load_balancing_policy=RoundRobinPolicy())
    s = cluster.connect(keyspace)
    s.row_factory = dict_factory
    return s

#initializing session in every process spawned by uwsgi
@postfork
def connect():
     global session
     session = get_new_session() 
     session.row_factory = dict_factory
```